# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 over network. Oledb Connection String

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection-string, oledbconnection

I cannot find an appropriate connection string to a Microsoft SQL server, it's the 2014 developer edition.
My current provider is this:

```
string strAccessConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=10.211.55.7;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=pos;Password=password;";
```

However, I get this error, 
[Error](http://hosting.chorkley.co.uk/SQL.jpg)

For reference, this is my source code.

```
string strAccessConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=10.211.55.7,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=pos;Password=password;";
string strAccessSelect = "SELECT userid FROM users";

DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;
try
{
    myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to create a database connection. \n{0}", ex.Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

try
{
    OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);
    OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

    myAccessConn.Open();
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Police");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase.\n{0}", ex.Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}
finally
{
    myAccessConn.Close();
}
```

I want to use the OleDbConnector.

Thank you!

Comment: I may want to switch to Oracle or MySQL

Comment: Why not DbConnection ?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971499.aspx

Comment: I've never used anything different. Have you got any good walkthroughs? 
If you've got a good clear walkthrough for SqlConnection, i'd love to give that a shot too!

When I attempted to use SqlConnection however, I got the same error as i'm having here.

Comment: SQL Management Studio logs in just fine. Same error when using instance name, however I only have the one instance installed.

I can login to the database from a remote computer too, it's just this code.
I've already followed that example too. It just doesn't work over the network.

Comment: That didn't make any change

Comment: Have you tried option " Click the ellipses (...) button in the Value field to open the Connection Properties dialog box to build your connection string " ?

Comment: It worked for the best part of 5 mins, and the same error came back. I have no idea as to what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to test, try adding the connection thus : [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171887.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171887.aspx)

" Click the ellipses (...) button in the Value field to open the Connection Properties dialog box to build your connection string "

There's the "magic"

Comment: It worked for the best part of 5 mins, and the same error came back. I have no idea as to what is happening

Comment: verify that you are using "ALWAYS" the connection string generated with this method ... and if the problem persists it may be a problem with the link