# Can not connect to database with IP address in WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, sql-server-2008-r2

I try to connect to database with an IP address from a WCF service in .net (Visual Studio 2012) and it doesn't connect.

To a local database, it connects and works fine.

My connection string is:

```
connectionString = "Data Source=XX.XXX.XXX.XX,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=XXXX;User ID=sa;Password=************;";
```

(The values are correct)

I also tried to add this property:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB
```

but it said that it couldn’t get this property.

Maybe there is a problem with the version?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try checking the Network Configuration Protocols for the server? Maybe it was set to disabled on the ip address you are trying to use. Go to SQL Server Network Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols ...

Comment: try adding the connection thus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326118/microsoft-sql-server-2014-over-network-oledb-connection-string/27326553#27326553